# Скрипт sql не запускается при старте приложения

Tags: java, spring, oracle, plsql, jdbc

Работаю над приложением на Spring Boot. Написал SQL скрипт для Oracle БД. Суть скрипта в том, чтобы при старте приложения проверялось наличие конкретного столбца в таблице. Если столбца нет, то необходимо его создать и скопировать в него данные из старого столбца из этой таблице.

Когда пробую запустить скрипт из DBeaver, то все отрабатывает нормально, но когда вставляю в .sql файл и запускаю приложение, то скрипт не срабатывает. Но необходимо, чтобы скрипт запускался сам каждый раз при старте приложения, так как приложение пишется для клиентов, а у них там некому запускать скрипты вручную после старта.

Приложению уже несколько лет, писал его не я.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему скрипт из .sql файла может не запускаться?

Вот сам скрипт:

```
DECLARE
  v_column_exists NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_column_exists
    FROM user_tab_cols
    WHERE UPPER(column_name) = 'password_clob'
      AND UPPER(table_name) = 'my_table';

  IF (v_column_exists = 0) THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (password_clob CLOB)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'UPDATE my_table SET password_clob = password';
  END IF;
END;
```

---

**Update**

Внёс правки, которые посоветовал [@0xdb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322062), но все равно пока не добился желаемого результата. Сыпятся ошибки:

```
2021-08-30 18:40:01.659DEBUG [main] (ScriptUtils.java:618) - Failed to execute SQL script statement #498 of class path resource [oracle/oracleScripts.sql]: DECLARE column_exists NUMBER
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 27, Sql = DECLARE column_exists NUMBER, OriginalSql = DECLARE column_exists NUMBER, Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

2021-08-30 18:40:01.662DEBUG [main] (ScriptUtils.java:618) - Failed to execute SQL script statement #499 of class path resource [oracle/oracleScripts.sql]: BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO column_exists FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = UPPER('my_table') AND column_name = UPPER('col2')
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 154:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;

Caused by: Error : 6550, Position : 153, Sql = BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO column_exists FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = UPPER('my_table') AND column_name = UPPER('col2'), OriginalSql = BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO column_exists FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = UPPER('my_table') AND column_name = UPPER('col2'), Error Msg = ORA-06550: line 1, column 154:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;

2021-08-30 18:40:01.668DEBUG [main] (ScriptUtils.java:618) - Failed to execute SQL script statement #500 of class path resource [oracle/oracleScripts.sql]: IF (column_exists = 0) THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (col2 CLOB)'
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Caused by: Error : 900, Position : 0, Sql = IF (column_exists = 0) THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (col2 CLOB)', OriginalSql = IF (column_exists = 0) THEN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (col2 CLOB)', Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

2021-08-30 18:40:01.669DEBUG [main] (ScriptUtils.java:618) - Failed to execute SQL script statement #501 of class path resource [oracle/oracleScripts.sql]: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE my_table SET col2 = col1'
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Caused by: Error : 900, Position : 0, Sql = EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE my_table SET col2 = col1', OriginalSql = EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE my_table SET col2 = col1', Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

2021-08-30 18:40:01.671DEBUG [main] (ScriptUtils.java:618) - Failed to execute SQL script statement #502 of class path resource [oracle/oracleScripts.sql]: END IF
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Caused by: Error : 900, Position : 0, Sql = END IF, OriginalSql = END IF, Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

2021-08-30 18:40:01.674DEBUG [main] (ScriptUtils.java:618) - Failed to execute SQL script statement #503 of class path resource [oracle/oracleScripts.sql]: END
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Caused by: Error : 900, Position : 0, Sql = END, OriginalSql = END, Error Msg = ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: *`WHERE UPPER(column_name) = 'password_clob'`* Вы хорошо понимаете, что делает функция `UPPER()`?

Comment: Только что прочитал. Вы указываете на то, что сравнивать нужно с названиями в верхнем регистре? Попробовал изменить на верхний регистр. Скрипт все равно не запускается. А из DBeaver запускается и отрабатывает

Comment: Скрипт сам по себе рабочий. Проблема в том, чтобы он запускался при старте приложения. Такие команды, как ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN...  у меня прописаны в файле .sql и они срабатывают при старте, а вот этот скрипт - нет

Comment: Ну в общем это как бы очевидный косяк. Не факт, конечно, что единственный... но если из DBeaver он работает корректно, то не исключено, что у Вас используется регистронезависимый collation (тогда UPPER вообще можно убрать за ненадобностью, кстати). Сейчас Вам надо определиться, что происходит. Либо скрипт не запускается вообще, либо запускается, но валится по ошибке (и тогда надо ловить, в каком месте и с какой ошибкой). См. напр. http://citforum.ru/database/oracle/oracle_trace01/

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю. А есть ли возможность вывести в логи то, что происходит во время выполнения скрипта? То есть хотя бы проверить, начинает ли он выполняться? И кстати, я пробовал прописать скрипт прямо в коде java и вызвал его в методе с аннотацией @Scheduled (автоматически запускает метод после старта приложения). Скрипт отрабатывает, но такой подход мне не нравится. Хочу, чтобы скрипт находился именно в файле .sql

Comment: А как вы вообще запускаете скрипт, покажите?

Comment: У меня есть файл, допустим oracleScripts.sql.
В этом файле прописаны все действия с таблицами бд, такие как создание таблиц, добавление колонок, удаление и т.д. Файл считывается при каждом запуске приложения.

Comment: @MShkolniy Оставте, пожалуйста, отклик - как удалось решить задачу, или нашли совсем другое решение?

Comment: Вариант, который я выбрал совсем мне не нравится и я бы не хотел, чтобы остальные брали с меня пример. Но в итоге я создал класс с методом. Метод аннотировал аннотацией @Scheduled(fixedDelay = Long.MAX_VALUE, initialDelay = 1000). В самом методе с помощью jdbcTemplate.query(......) запутил скрипт. Сейчас код не перед глазами, более точно сказать не могу..

Comment: Спустя время новые задачи вынудили добавить ещё пару таких же скриптов в java код. Сегодня прилетела ещё одна задача, которая требовала применить очередной непростой скрипт. В итоге привязал к проекту liquibase и переписал все скрипты туда:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Анонимный блок в вопросе почти рабочий. Устранил некоторые логичские ошибки и добавил вывод для диагностики ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5e2ee2f8fa590eeb56eff67c4ccea7db)):

```
DECLARE
    column_exists NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO column_exists
    FROM user_tab_cols
    WHERE table_name  = UPPER('my_table')
    AND   column_name = UPPER('col2');
    dbms_output.put_line ('column_exists='||column_exists); 
    IF (column_exists = 0) THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE my_table ADD (col2 CLOB)';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE my_table SET col2 = col1';
        dbms_output.put_line ('column added rowcount='||sql%rowcount); 
    ELSE 
        dbms_output.put_line ('nothing to do'); 
    END IF;
END;
/
```

> Хочу, чтобы скрипт находился именно в файле .sql

Прямого способа отправить на выполнение файл .sql на сервер БД не существует. Любой инструмент или любая библиотека, которые могут обработать файлы .sql, делают нечего иного, как:

- считывают **отдельные** SQL запросы или PL/SQL блоки из файла
- отправляют их *"поштучно"* на выполнение серверу БД

---

**Update**

Класс [ScriptUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.html), которым ТС пытается запустить файл .sql, расчитан на  "чистые" SQL скрипты, т.е. состоящие только из SQL выражений, коим PL/SQL блок не является.

По умолчанию метод `executeSqlScript` использует ";" как разделитель отдельных SQL выражений, но в PL/SQL блоке этот символ является частью синтаксиса. Как следствие, на сервер БД отправляются обрывки PL/SQL блока:

```
DECLARE column_exists NUMBER
                        ----^ здесь ";" был воспринят как разделитель и удалён  
ORA-06550: line 1, column 28:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
          ----^ синтаксически здесь ожидается этот символ
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант, но все равно колонка не добавляется. Программа доходит до выполнения скрипта, но дальше идут ошибками с самой первой строки. Ошибки следующего содержания: добавил как ответ, т.к. здесь не умещается

Comment: @MShkolniy Дополнил ответ, посмотрите. Почему вы проигнорировали [коментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321486/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-sql-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment2334842_1321486) с просьбой показать, как запускается скрипт из файла?

Comment: сначала не совсем понял как описать процесс того, как я запускаю скрипт. Да и на выходных не было возможности ответить. Я пока не уверен, что у меня используется класс ScriptUtils, сейчас доеду до работы и посмотрю ещё раз. В любом случае, большое спасибо за ваши ответы. Я правильно понимаю, что таким способом у меня не получится запустить скрипт? Возможно, есть какая-нибудь альтернатива?

Comment: У меня файл с sql командами передается в параметры класса ClassPathResource. Тот в свою очередь присваивается переменной класса Resource (package org.springframework.core.io;).
Этот эксземляр класса Resource передается в метод addScript класса ResourceDatabasePopulator.
В классе ResourceDatabasePopulator задействован класс ScriptUtils. Похоже, вы правы насчет ScriptUtils.

Comment: @MShkolniy _Возможно, есть какая-нибудь альтернатива?_, алтернатива всегда есть: а) попробовать изменить раазделитель по-умолчанию ";" на другой, большинство инструментов используют слэш "/" на новой строке б) если не получится, то написать свой класс, подобный ScriptUtils.

Comment: @MShkolniy Почти тоже самое советует один из разработчиков spring [@SamBrannen в своём ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31190323).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. К сожалению, я не рискну воспользоваться этим способом - мой файл содержит несколько тысяч строк с различными командами. Если менять разделить, то придётся вставить его после каждой команды.. велика вероятность допустить ошибку.

Comment: @MShkolniy Тогда только второй путь - писать свой класс, который предусмотрит оба разделителя. Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как принятый, он отвечает на ваш вопрос, а предложить решение, которое бы решило полностью вашу задачу в рамках одного ответа, в данном случае невозможно.